# Gradients and Mean Value Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Please note that the following question is not for an assignment. The following question is for exam preparation.

"Let $F:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{p}$ be differentiable and let $B(\mathbf{a},r)=\{\mathbf{x} \in U \mid ||\mathbf{x-a}|| < r\}$. Show for $\mathbf{x,\,y}\in B(\mathbf{a},r)$, there exists $\mathbf{c}_{1},\dots,\mathbf{c}_{p} \in B(\mathbf{a},r)$, such that

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{y})-\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x})= \begin{pmatrix} \nabla F_{1}(\mathbf{c}_{1}) \\ \vdots \\ \nabla F_{p}(\mathbf{c}_{p}) \end{pmatrix} (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x})."
\end{equation}

---

I am editing to incorporate the fact that I've found that

\begin{equation}
F(\mathbf{y})- F(\mathbf{x})= \nabla F(\mathbf{c}) (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x})."
\end{equation}

can be proven by first parametrizing the line $\overline{\mathbf{yx}}$ and then setting $\mathbf{c}=\mathbf{y}+t(\mathbf{y-x})$.

I am still not completely sure how to generalize this for a vector-value function $\mathbf{F}$.

Comment: Did you try 'ignoring' the fact that this is in $\mathbb{R}^p$ for now and try it in 1-dimension? Then you have $F(y)-F(x)=\frac{df}{dx}|_{c}(y-x)$ for some $c$. You should recognize this statement. Try and prove it yourself and study your method carefully. This will make it 'easy' to do the multivariable case as very little changes.

Comment: You have shown the statement for $p = 1$. Now use this result $p$ times and write it in vector notation.

Comment: @HansEngler Thanks, guys!

Comment: From where did you find the result? This result is WRONG!